# jquery dynamic nested list expand collapse click on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I am generating a nested list.
jquery is not working "dynamic nested list expand collapse click on a div"

could you please any one help me.

when I click on 000 then the function expand collapse should run

```js
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
  $('li.dropdown').not(this).find('ul').hide();
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">Data mining and data warehousing
    <div class="buttonShow">000</div>
    <ul>
      <li>Data mining techniques
        <div class="buttonShow">000</div>
      </li>
      <li>Knowledge discovery
        <div class="buttonShow">
          000</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown">Soft computing and artificial intelligence
    <div class="buttonShow">000</div>
    <ul>
      <li>Fuzzy systems
        <div class="buttonShow">000</div>
      </li>
      <li>Neural networks
        <div class="buttonShow">000</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the problem, everything seems to work for me

Comment: are you trying to say that event on child 'li's not working ?

Comment: There was no HTML in the OP's question. It was introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44645656/2). Ideally, the OP should have been asked to provide his HTML.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb, It was there, As OP is new he didn't formatted correctly

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb The HTML was there, it was just not in code format, So all we saw was lots of  `000` [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44645656/1)

Comment: I missed it. You guys are right.

Comment: hi guys, it is expanding when i am clicking on li also. i don't want that.

Comment: it should expand when i click on 000 div not on li tag